# Python Pandas performance

Tags: python, performance, pandas

Someone told if you are looping in python you are doing something wrong, and I tend to agree with that, so I did some perf. analysis on my program and I'm surprised by the results:

I'm trying to retrieving the indexes of the non-Nan data of a pandas Series with dropna(), and it seems to be slower than looping :

```
from pandas import Series
import numpy as np
import timeit

def test1():
    s = Series([25.9,25.8,np.nan,34.8],index=['a','b','c','d'])
    return s.dropna().index

def test2():
    s = Series([25.9,25.8,np.nan,34.8],index=['a','b','c','d'])
    res = []
    for i in s.index:
        if not np.isnan(s[i]):
            res.append(i)
    return res


>>> timeit.timeit(test1,number=10000)
1.931797840017623
>>> timeit.timeit(test2,number=10000)
1.602180508842423
```

---

Am I missing something here? Or it is just because I'm returning an array instead of pandas index?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although pandas-apostoles won't agree, pandas is not the answer to everything. Choose always the tool which fits best for the job and don't believe anyone saying "library XYZ is the best for everything" or "If you are X'ing, you are doing something wrong". Under the hood, your library is X'ing again.

Answer (score 4):

These are **very** small Series. Try with a larger one:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([25.9,25.8,np.nan,34.8] * 1000)

In [12]: %timeit [i for i in s.index if not np.isnan(s[i])]
10 loops, best of 3: 34.9 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit s.dropna().index
10000 loops, best of 3: 106 µs per loop
```

*Note: I've used a list comprehension, which may be slightly faster than your impl.*